# What is the definition of Pandas Series right join?

Tags: pandas, time-series

Given two series, `s1` and `s2`, are these two snippets of code equivalent?

```
s1, _ = s1.align(s2, join='right')
```

and

```
for k in s2.index:
    if not k in s1.index:
        s1[k] = np.nan
```

Comment: right join , look at the index of s1 , and if s2 index exist append it , if not return NaN

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the 2 codes are equivalent, but if `s2` is bigger than `s1`, than the second option with `for` loop becomes much slower comparing to the first one `align`